# Flutter desktop - sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.2.5 is not working on release mode

Tags: flutter, sqflite, flutter-windows

I'm using sqflite_common_ffi: ^2.2.5 on flutter desktop to store data locally, it works perfectly fine on debug mode but its not working in release mode.

I tried adding sqlite3.dll on the same folder as my executable but still it's not working on release mode.(See images below)

[sqlite3 on release directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VimQ5.png)
[sqlite3 in creating installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRdo0.png)